# Se não tiver valor para comparar, salvar sem fazer a comparação

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

Estou tentando fazer com que minha aplicação salve se não tiver nenhum valor para comparar, porem sempre ta passando pela comparação, já tentei coloca um if porém continua com problema, essa aqui é a classe que faz a comparação entre minha view e meu banco de dados.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Adiciona(RotaModel viewModel)
    { 

            var rotas = ckm.Consulta(viewModel.NumCarroId);
            //  Aqui busca todas as rotas deste veículo

            var maiorRota = rotas.OrderByDescending(r => r.Km).FirstOrDefault();
            //  Aqui você tem a última rota cadastrada, considerando a regra geral  


            if (viewModel.Km < maiorRota.Km)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Km_Atual.Invalido",
                "A quilometragem precisa ser maior que a anterior");
            }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            Rota rota = viewModel.CriaRota();
            dao.Adiciona(rota);
            //return View();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        else
            {
            ViewBag.Usuarios = usuarioDAO.Lista();
            ViewBag.Veiculo = veiculoDAO.Lista();
            return View("Form", viewModel);
            }
    }
```

Quando  tento salva sem nenhum valor pré registrado, ele aparece o seguinte erro.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault()` sem argumento por **default** traz o valor nulo quando não encontrado um valor dentro de sua coleção. O que acontece é que se ele não encontrar nada você vai estar acessando uma propriedade (.Km) de uma referência nula, isso vai causar o seu `NullReferenceException`

Você precisa validar quando não houver nenhuma rota maior para fazer a comparação. Um exemplo de como validar:

```
var maiorRota = rotas.OrderByDescending(r => r.Km).FirstOrDefault();

if (maiorRota != null && viewModel.Km < maiorRota.Km)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Km_Atual.Invalido",
            "A quilometragem precisa ser maior que a anterior");
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, mas desculper meio que pedir mais uma coisa, mas poderia me explica oque seria esse != null e como seria interpreta-lo

Comment: Sem problemas, o motivo do forum é perguntar e fico feliz em responder. `null` é uma "representação" que minha variável não referência nada. Se eu tentar acessar algo de uma variável que referência nada, ocorre essa exceção. Então a interpretação seria: **Se minha maiorRota tiver algo para referênciar**.

Comment: Eu estava tentando fazer so que de vez null eu colocava o 0, e estava criando um outro if/else pra tentar fazer isso, mas mesmo assim estava dando errado, desse modo fico muito mais curto e facil de entender.